# Using global variable has the potential to change module behavior during the import?

Tags: python, import, module, global-variables

By [Google Python style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html#Global_variables), one disadvantage of using global variables is this:

> "Has the potential to change module behavior during the import, because assignments to module-level variables are done when the module is imported".

My understanding to the sentence is, "the module level variables of the imported module `A` effect the behavior of module `B` which imports module `A`", is this semantically correct?

If it is, any module level variable var in `A` can only be accessed in `B` by `A.var`. I don't get why importing `A` would change the behavior of `B`.

If I misunderstand the sentence, what is the correct interpretation?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the statement refers to `from x import *` could it be?

Comment: This might not be the case, since the style guide discussed the disadvantage of "from x import *" (giving x is a module not the prefix of a package name) before introducing the topic discussed here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an import cache that avoids re-importing the same module multiple times during the execution of a single program.

However, a module-level global could for example, be set to a random number seeded by time.time() or similar.  If the random number is used as a divisor, sometimes when you import the module, you get division by zero, and sometimes you don't.

Comment: In your case, even if the random number is *not* a module-level variable, it is still possible to get the division by zero exception.  Does the importing behavior play any role here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After considering my question for some time, I have the following idea.

Considering the following three files:

File 1: foo.py

```
x = 1
```

File 2: bar.py

```
import foo
foo.x = 2
def func():
  pass
```

File 3: main.py

```
import foo
foo.x = 3

# Now I need some function in bar...    
import bar
bar.func()

print foo.x
```

By only browsing *main.py*, it is hard to imagine why *foo.x* would be 2.  This is because when *main.py* imports *bar*, the value of *foo.x* is being changed in *bar.py*.

It might not be the best answer.  You are welcome to correct me or add more explanations.